# jQuery AJAX call using POST to reload a selector

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use jQuery to send a POST (and later a DELETE) AJAX request to replace the current functionality of `$("#memberResults").load(url)`. I need to load the same URL, but with a verb of POST or DELETE depending on if I'm adding or deleting a member to my REST service. I should clarify that the url first goes to my java backend.

I've tried to use the $.ajax method, but can't seem to get it to work properly. This code will add the member properly but does not do the AJAX refresh (I need to refresh the whole page to see the change).

```
function addMember(){

    var member = document.getElementById('memQueryResult').innerHTML;
    var role = document.getElementById('roleChosen').innerHTML;
    var url = '/roles/' + role + '/' + member;

    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        type : 'POST',
        success : function(url) {
            $("#memberResults").load(url);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't get the question. You do Ajax call, than you do `.load(dataFromServer)`... What you expect to happen?

Comment: @Justinas I'm only using the .load() because I don't see where to add a selector in the $.ajax. The call should reach out to my java function that will add/delete the given member, then reload the list of members displayed on my site with the given selector.

Comment: @Justinas it seems my code actually works. But, it doesn't refresh the selected ID properly. I've updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first do your POST/DELETE request and on success just replace element with content from server response (that contains new reloaded items list)

```
var ajaxType = getAction(); // returns 'POST' or 'DELETE'
var url = '/roles/' + $('#roleChosen').text() + '/' + $('#memQueryResult').text();

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: ajaxType,
    success: function (response) {
        $('#memberResults').replaceWith(response);
    }
});
```

---

`document.getElementById('memQueryResult').innerHTML` can be replaced to jQuery `$('memQueryResult').html()`